# OnPostExecute not working , not able to draw graph

Tags: java, android, android-activity, android-asynctask

`onButtonClcick` to button `index` , A `graph` should be displayed which gets the data from URL. I've used `AsyncTask` for the same.

I'm stuck between two approaches.

1) If I call `afterload()` method in `postExecute()` which is called on `index` button click, I'm just getting the 1st screenshot as shown below i.e. **GRAPH IS NOT GETTING DISPLAYED**.

I debugged it to find that afterload() method was called but still graph was not displayed.

2) If I don't call `afterload()` method in `postExecute()`. Instead I copied all content of `afterload()` method into `onCreate()` method new class `graphView` ,then **GRAPH IS GETTING DISPLAYED**. as shown in 2nd screenshot

BUT **ALL THE OTHER FUNCTIONALITY LIKE ONCLICKLISTENERS, FILTERING LIST DATA IS LOST**. (note that in 2nd screenshot table is not getting displayed). This is due to using `setContentView()` in second activity and hence layout is getting re-launched thus control coming to the second activity.

**ANY HELP WILL BE LIFE-SAVER !!!**

**DataAttach.java**

```
    public class DataAttach extends Activity {
        //ALL VARIABLES DECLARED

        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.main);
            init();
        }

        public void init() {
            //ALL FINDBYVIEWID COMMANDS

            DownloadWebPageTask task = new DownloadWebPageTask();
            task.execute(new String[] { "http://abc.com/" });

                ed.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

                    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start,
                            int before, int count) {
                        //filtering listview data
                    }
                });

                lsym.setOnItemClickListener(new android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                            int position, long id) {

                    }
                });

                btnindex.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(View v) {

                        mySimpleXYPlot.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        WebPageTask task1 = new WebPageTask();
                        task1.execute(new String[] { "http://pqr.com/" });
                    }
                });

                btngainer.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        DownloadWebPageTask task = new DownloadWebPageTask();
                        task.execute(new String[] { "http://xyz.com/" });
                    }
                });

                btnloser.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        DownloadWebPageTask task = new DownloadWebPageTask();
                        task.execute(new String[] { "http://ijk.com/" });
                    }
                });

            finally {
                dbM.close();
            }
        }

        private class DownloadWebPageTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
            //DO SOMETHING
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
                //DO SOMETHING
            }
        }

        private class WebPageTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
            @Override
            protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {
                   //FETCHING DATA FROM URL
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(String result) {

                //POPULATING 'time' & 'current' ARRAYS

                afterload(time, current);
  //============================================================================
  //============================================================================
 //IF I USE BELOW COMMENTED CODE THEN IT DISPLAYS GRAPH BUT ALL THE ONCLICKLISTENERS DOESN'T WORK.
  //============================================================================
  //============================================================================
                // Bundle b = new Bundle();
                // b.putStringArray("time", time);
                // b.putStringArray("current", current);
                //
                // Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), DrawGraph.class);
                // i.putExtras(b);
                // DataAttach.this.startActivity(i);
            }

            public void afterload(String[] time, String[] current) {

            //POPULATING 'timenumber' & 'currentnumber' ARRAYS

                Number[] series1Numbers = timenumber;
                Number[] series2Numbers = currentnumber;

                XYSeries series1 = new SimpleXYSeries(
                        Arrays.asList(series1Numbers),
                        Arrays.asList(series2Numbers), "Reliance");

                LineAndPointFormatter series1Format = new LineAndPointFormatter(
                        Color.rgb(0, 200, 0), // line color
                        Color.rgb(0, 100, 0), // point color
                        Color.rgb(150, 190, 150)); // fill color (optional)

                mySimpleXYPlot.addSeries(series1, series1Format);
                mySimpleXYPlot.setTicksPerRangeLabel(2);
                mySimpleXYPlot.setTicksPerDomainLabel(2);
                mySimpleXYPlot.setRangeStep(XYStepMode.INCREMENT_BY_VAL, 1);
                mySimpleXYPlot.setDomainStep(XYStepMode.SUBDIVIDE, 10);
                mySimpleXYPlot.setDomainValueFormat(new MyDateFormat());
                mySimpleXYPlot.disableAllMarkup();
            }
        }

        public class MyDateFormat extends Format {
            //CONVERTING DATE FORMAT
    }
```

**1ST & 2ND SCREENSHOT ARE TAKEN BEFORE & AFTER CLICKING `INDEX` BUTTON.**

[image: SCREENSHOT]

Comment: You can try to move your graph into another included layout.Maybe that does not flush your list data.

Comment: What type **mySimpleXYPlot** of?

Comment: @NOSTRA XYPlot. I'm using android plot and imported the required library.

Comment: @Yahor10 - You want to say that I should include graph into another layout say `graph.xml`, include `graph.xml` in `main.xml`? and set ContenrView to `graph.xml` for 2nd activity????

Comment: @GAMA yes.And this redraw only your graph.xml

Comment: Did you try do **mySimpleXYPlot.redraw()** or **mySimpleXYPlot.postRedraw()** at the end of **afterload()** method?

Comment: @NOSTRA - using `mySimpleXYPlot.redraw()` worked like a charm. Post it again as an ans, I'll accept it. But what was the problem?

Comment: It's not a problem, you should call **redraw()** after you change the graph data and want to display actual graph view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use **mySimpleXYPlot.redraw()** or **mySimpleXYPlot.postRedraw()** at the end of afterload() method.

If you see the sources: **redraw()** method invalidates view, so your data will be displayed.